# Insert DateTime into MS Access

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

How to convert DateTime in java to the format that match with MS Access database?
This is how I format the date:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String stringDate = dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(stringDate);
```

Then this is my SQL query:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblBorrows(DateIn) VALUES (" + dateFormat.parse(stringDate) + ")";
```

I print out the `stringDate`, it gives me `2016/03/29 16:42:24`, but for my sql it is `INSERT INTO tblBorrows(DateIn) VALUES (Tue Mar 29 16:42:24 SGT 2016)`

This is my exception message: 
`net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.4 unexpected token: MAR required: )`

Inside my MS Access, I select General Date as my Date/Time format:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblBorrows(DateIn) VALUES (" + dateFormat.parse(stringDate) + ")";
```

to

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblBorrows(DateIn) VALUES (#" stringDate + "#)";
```

Maybe you should try to do database manipulation with prepared statements:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcMsAccess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + 
                    "Dbq=C:\\__tmp\\Database1.accdb;");
            Date date = new Date();
            PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO tblBorrows(DateIn) VALUES (?)");
            s.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
            s.execute();
            s.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me `incompatible type: Date cannot be converted to String`

Comment: now it gives me :`net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.4 unexpected token: 18 required: )`
SQL: `INSERT INTO tblBorrows(DateIn) VALUES (2016/03/29 18:27:30)`
I think the `18` it is talking about is from time `18:27:30`

Comment: I think you were missing ' in query string, so I added it. Test it.

Comment: Yes, I used wrong delimiter. I am also suggesting usage of prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. My only suggestion would be to remove the string formatting nonsense altogether and just leave the PreparedStatement example. If they already have a `Date` then formatting it as a string and using dynamic SQL is just foolish.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct delimiters for datetime in Access:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblBorrows(DateIn) VALUES (#" + stringDate + "#)";
```